# google spreadsheet array length varies. I'm left with -- after shorter array calculations

Tags: arraylist, spreadsheet

In google spreadsheet,  my array length varies.  I'm left with -- or a double dash after a shorter input is calculated  and placed into the array or if i clear the input entirely.

```
Ex.formula   =iferror(if(E10="",transpose(split(upper(D1),",")),query(vlist)),"")
```

The above will either take input from E10 or D1.  If i clear all the input im left with -- in some cells. If shorter input is calculted I'm also left with -- in previous longer array positions.

1. Is there any way I can eliminate the possibliity of -- appearing in
   cells?
2. Maybe I the original question should be, **How can a fixed array
   ignore null values and not output -- or double dash.**

Comment: Actually, this question should rather be in [Web Applications](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I have been struggling with this, too. And now i found a workaround to it in [this forum answer](http://productforums.google.com/d/msg/docs/1hEWTjYTJBQ/7JgaSQjREWcJ).

The workaround is not to suppress the `--` directly, but to handle them in the cells that *use this data*. You can handle them with the `ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(` functions.

I realized that if you have **several** cells where you use this data, instead of changing all these cells, a more comfortable way to do this is to

- create an (invisible?) "helper" array somewhere else in your sheet, where you put your formula that creates the `--`
- apply the workaround in the cell where you originally had your formula.

Example:

Cell `A1` contains `=SORT(UNIQUE(Sheet2!X:X))` (which eventually results in `--` in the cells `A2`, `A3`,... if the number of unique values in column `X` on sheet 2 decreases).

Workaround: Use your formula `=SORT(UNIQUE(Sheet2!X:X))` e.g. in cell `B1` and put `=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(B:B))` in `A1`.